# Can I reuse the certificate when setting up OpenVPN over stunnel?

Tags: openvpn, certificates, stunnel

I am setting up an **OpenVPN** server to run over **stunnel** following [this](http://safesrv.net/install-and-setup-openvpn-stealth-with-stunnel/) tutorial.

It asks that I create a *self-signed certificate* for **stunnel** on the server side. Since I already have one that was created for **OpenVPN**, I was wondering if it would be possible to use that and if it would be smart and why/why not.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can. And no you should not (unless operating on a non-public net, which seems very very unlikely due to OpenVPN being a public access method to private subnet(s)).

The reasons why correspond to the TLS protocols certificate validation process and the trust worthiness of the connections when

1. It is self signed and not signed by a reputable certificate authority, this can and will lead to a MITM attack vector because no validation can or will occur during the initial handshake process.
2. Now the private key used previously is being re-used negating (if it were moved from one device to another) the security protections of a 'private key'. There is an exception to this when using protocols such as SCP to move the file.